# What Does "itersLeft" Mean?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python via the MIT OpenWare courses and generally the instructor is pretty good about explaining things as he goes. However today he used the expression "itersLeft" in a bit of code and went right over it assuming everyone knew what it meant. I've tried Googling it but with little luck. Can anyone explain what that means and what it's function is?

Code:

```
y = 0 
x = 3 
itersLeft = x 
while(itersLeft>0):
    y = y = x
    itersLeft = itersLeft - 1
    #print 'y =',y,',itersLeft=',itersLeft
    print y
```

EDIT:

Here's a link to the vid: [Lec 2 | MIT 6.00 Introduction to Computer Science and Programming](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pij6J0HsYFA&p=4C4720A6F225E074)

Here's a link to the full code: [Code Link](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/50241/6-00Fall-2007/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-00Fall-2007/7F773318-698A-4187-9EFC-911A0A5DE5B3/0/lec2.pdf.txt?sequence=203)

Thinking it may be short hand for "integers left".. I dunno :/

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aiteration

Answer (score 6):

Without having seen anything related to the code, I would say either of "iterations remaining" or "iterators remaining".

**EDIT:**

It's a name. It binds to an object. Just like `x`, `y`, or `numberOfItemsLeftInTheFridge`.

Comment: Sorry
'code'
y = 0
x = 3
itersLeft = x
while(itersLeft>0):
    y = y = x
    itersLeft = itersLefr - 1
    #print 'y =',y,',itersLeft=',itersLeft
print y'/code'

Comment: So yes, "iterations remaining".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `itersLeft` is a Python module or function. Google not finding anything on it is more evidence on that.

I guess it's a name meaning `iterations left (remaining)` or `iterations on the left side` (possibly iterating in a binary tree).

Comment: Here's the link [1]: http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/50241/6-00Fall-2007/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-00Fall-2007/7F773318-698A-4187-9EFC-911A0A5DE5B3/0/lec2.pdf.txt?sequence=203

Answer (score 0):

It means integers left, as in how many whole numbers are remaining for the repetition addition that he is doing with this section of code!