# What does this itersleft mean

Tags: python-3.x, statements

Does anyone know what itersleft means in Python? I'm currently taking a computer science course and I cannot find the answer anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890857/what-does-itersleft-mean

Comment: @vaultah: nice find.